# How to automatically generate a table of contents for a list of nodes?

Tags: views, nodes

I want to generate a table of contents made up of the titles of the nodes listed within a view, which will then be displayed at the top of that view. The nodes are of just one content type.

I've spent the last couple of days [looking through the pre-existing modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2278811), but thus far they all seem to generate TOCs only for one particular node.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the attachment display in Views.

1. Create your normal view
2. Add an attachment display to that view:

[image]

3. Set "Attach to" to your normal view display
4. Configure the attachment display to show titles of your content types nodes.

Comment: Ah, I was focussing too much on finding a module rather than just building it myself. Many thanks, that worked very well. Also, for anyone in future looking for help with connecting up the in-page anchor links, I found this link useful: https://www.drupal.org/node/1253530.